# Delete a part of string from Android edit text when deleting

Tags: android, android-edittext

When deleting characters from EditText, I want to delete  a complete text if it matches a string.That is I have a string with value abc and if I am deleting characters from edit text and it contains abc I need to delete the whole word abc(not by character by character).Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome in advance! can you explain more?

Comment: @PankajKumar   There is a word abc in edittext. After deleting some characters user is now at c. When he tries to delete c , abc should be deleted not only c

Answer (score 0):

Register a handler for the onKeyPress of EditText, when you get the `KEYCODE` for the delete button, handle it and use something like this:

```
String a = "aaabccc";
String b = "abc";
EditText et;
if(a.contains(b) && ((a.indexOf(b) + b.length()) == et.getSelectionStart())
{
            et.setText(et.getText().delete(et.getSelectionStart()-b.length(), et.getSelectionStart())).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good way to do it is creating a TextWatcher:

```
private final TextWatcher mTextEditorWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        public int oldLength = 0;
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            if ((oldLength > s.length())){
                editText.setText("");
                oldLength = 0;
            }else
                oldLength = s.length();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
editText.addTextChangedListener(mTextEditorWatcher);
```